# Can't set up a HTTP CGI Server in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, cgi

Does anyone notice this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
from CGIHTTPServer import CGIHTTPRequestHandler


class Handler(CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    cgi_directories = ["/"]


httpd = HTTPServer(("", 8000), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 6, in <module>
    from CGIHTTPServer import CGIHTTPRequestHandler
  File "C:\Python27\lib\CGIHTTPServer.py", line 30, in <module>
    import SimpleHTTPServer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 27, in <module>
    class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 208, in SimpleHTTPRequestHan
ler
    mimetypes.init() # try to read system mime.types
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 358, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 258, in read_windows_registry
    for subkeyname in enum_types(hkcr):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 2: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

I used to run this code in the past and it works right, but now it simply doesn't. The code works perfect in Python 3 (changing the imports).

Running Python 2.7.6 on Windows 8 (both 64 bits). Reinstalling Python doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This is an issue because of the encoding in the Windows registry caused by the mimetypes module. If anybody find the same problem in the future, [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue9291) is the patch to solve it. If you don't want to waste your time checking that, here's the quick solution. Replace the `enum_types()` function from the mimetypes module (`Lib/mimetypes.py`) with this one:

```
from itertools import count
def enum_types(mimedb):
    for i in count():
        try:
            yield _winreg.EnumKey(mimedb, i)
        except EnvironmentError:
            break
```

Thanks to all.